# How to create a a checkbox/radiobutton for every choice of an attrubute using django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter, django-widget

I have a model `Property`

```
class Property(models.Model):

PROPERTY_CATEGORIES = (
('flat/apartment 1BHK','flat/apartment 1BHK'),
('flat/apartment 2BHK','flat/apartment 2BHK'),
('flat/apartment 3BHK','flat/apartment 3BHK'),
('house','house'),
('pg/hostel +1 mate','pg/hostel +1 mate'),
('pg/hostel +2 mate','pg/hostel +2 mate'),
('pg/hostel +3 mate','pg/hostel +3 mate'),
('pg/hostel +4 mate','pg/hostel +4 mate'),    
)

name        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
proptype    = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PROPERTY_CATEGORIES)
```

and my filters.py looks like this

```
import django_filters
from .models import Property
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class PropertyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    PROPERTY_CATEGORIES = (
    ('flat/apartment 1BHK','flat/apartment 1BHK'),
    ('flat/apartment 2BHK','flat/apartment 2BHK'),
    ('flat/apartment 3BHK','flat/apartment 3BHK'),
    ('house','house'),
    ('pg/hostel +1 mate','pg/hostel +1 mate'),
    ('pg/hostel +2 mate','pg/hostel +2 mate'),
    ('pg/hostel +3 mate','pg/hostel +3 mate'),
    ('pg/hostel +4 mate','pg/hostel +4 mate'),    
    )
    proptype = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=PROPERTY_CATEGORIES)
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['proptype']
        filter_overrides = {
                         models.CharField:{
                 'filter_class' : django_filters.ChoiceFilter,
                 'extra' : lambda f: {
                     'widget' : 'forms.CheckboxInput'
                 }
             }
        }
```

and my html file is

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="get">
        <!-- {{ filter.form.as_p }} -->
        {% for choice in filter.form.proptype %}
        {{ choice.choice_label }}
        <span class="radio">{{ choice.tag }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    {% for obj in filter.qs %}
        {{ obj }} <br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want to display the choices like as radiobuttons or checkboxes

like
[a list of categories like house, flat etc like with radiobuttons to select them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITZCl.png)

but I cant find a way to do this please help

Answer (score 1):

`forms.CheckboxInput` only renders one checkout out, used mainly for boolean(True or False) selection. you need to use `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple`or `forms.RadioSelect` instead.

```
class PropertyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...
    proptype = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=PROPERTY_CATEGORIES)
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ['proptype']
        filter_overrides = {
            models.CharField:{
                 'filter_class' : django_filters.ChoiceFilter,
                 'extra' : lambda f: {
                      #'widget' : forms.RadioSelect
                      'widget' : forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
                 }
             }
        }
```

for further customization
you can use a customized or [builtin widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#built-in-widgets) and pass attributes like `placeholder, class` to control how the form looks, which has the same API with forms. Internally, `Filter` class hold a default form `Field` as a class attribute,  paramters defined on the `Filter` related to form are passed to form `Field` to render the HTML.

for example:

```
from django.forms.widgets import Input

django_filters.CharFilter(label='name_starts', method=filter_name_starts, 
    widget = Input(attrs={'placeholder':'filter by first letter...', 'class': 'form-control'}))
```